# How to update python 2.6.6 to Python 3?

Tags: linux, debian, python

I have debian 6.0 64bit and I need to update my python 2.6.6, It's the wrong version for my needs and now have to remove the 2.6.6 and upgrade to 3. Any help please? I'm not a Linux Savy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aptitude install python3
```

Follow that up by any bits and bobs you might need on top.

```
aptitude search python3
```

to see what's available.

If you *really* must remove 2.6 (note that they live happily side by side):

```
aptitude remove python2.6
```

Comment: removing python 2.x is a VERY VERY bad idea. You want to start python scripts with the version on it, and removing python 2 WILL BREAK THINGS VERY BADLY

Comment: AFAIK removing python 2.6 will break your lunix because parts of it use it, so it will be partially equal to rm -rf /